# Spring OAuth Authorization Server behind Spring Cloud Zuul Proxy

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am currently developing a application based on a micro service architecture. We use a API-Gateway implemented using Spring Cloud Netfix's Zuul Server to route the requests to our micro services.

To realize single sign on for all our services I am currently working on an OAuth2 server set up using Spring Cloud Security. The server is basically just copy and past of the implementation in Dave Syer's Repo: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/tree/master/oauth2/authserver

The main difference is that I want to route the requests to my OAuth server through the Zuul Proxy. This way I will not have to directly expose my OAuth Server and can add and remove Login Server dynamically.

The problem is I do not seam to understand how to correctly configure this setup. When I try to access a protected resource on the OAuth server I am forwarded to the login page. This of course is as expected. But I can not figure out how to set the hostname and port used when forwarding. What I want to happen is the server to forward to an endpoint on the Zuul server that will get proxied back to the OAuth server. (The Zuul API-Gateway should be the only server the client ever talks to. Everything else will be hidden.)

As it is the host and port are read from the `HttpServletRequest` in `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`. But the request the server sees is the request send by the Zuul proxy. So I am forwarded to an internal IP not an endpoint on the proxy.

I tried to set the URL of the login page in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity)` to the absolut URL of my Zuul Proxy. But this just caused my application to complain about too many redirects. (Might have caused a loop there.)

What would be the best way to set this up?

- Do I have to implement some kind of own forwarding strategy by overriding a bean?
- Is there a configuration option I am missing?
- Is my idea itself wrong? (In his answer to [How to avoid redirect to another host with Zuul?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417005/how-to-avoid-redirect-to-another-host-with-zuul?answertab=votes#tab-top) Dave Syer says you would not normally proxy this but does not explain why.)

Comment: So in the end how do you proceed with this issue?

Comment: Could you please add how did you sort this out and implement?

Comment: I accepted the highest ranked answer for now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update**: POC can be found here https://github.com/kakawait/uaa-behind-zuul-sample

---

Did you try following setup (on `zuul` server):

```
zuul:
  routes:
    uaa-service:
      path: /uaa/**
      stripPrefix: false

security:
  # Disable Spring Boot basic authentication
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    sso:
      loginPath: /login
    client:
      accessTokenUri: https://<zuul hostname>/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://<zuul hostname>/uaa/oauth/authorize
      ...
```

Basically it works on my project only thing I have to do is to disable `CSRF` protection on `/uaa/oauth/token` route.

Auth server should be on

```
server:
  # Use different context-path to avoid session cookie overlapping
  context-path: /uaa
```

Tested using `Spring-Cloud.Brixton.M3`

---

Thank to [@thomas-letsch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309964/thomas-letsch), you should tweak you security like following (sample)

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
    http.logout().and()
        .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests() 
        .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/", "/uaa/oauth/**").permitAll() 
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and() 
        .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(getCSRFTokenRepository()).ignoringAntMatchers("/uaa/‌​oauth/token").and() 
        .addFilterAfter(createCSRFHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class); 
}
```

Comment: This works for me as well. I had to exclude the /uaa/oauth path from security. See this part from my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

Comment: public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.logout().and()
                .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/", "/uaa/oauth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(getCSRFTokenRepository()).ignoringAntMatchers("/uaa/oauth/token").and()
                .addFilterAfter(createCSRFHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }

Comment: In my personal case I rewrite `OAuth2ClientContextFilter` to support `URI` (and not only `URL`) thus I can use `accessTokenUri: /uaa/oauth/token`. And for `userAuthorizationUri` I use `localhost` like following `userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost/uaa/oauth/authorize`. Thus configuration is portable (I don't need to know where UAA is located). I opened an issue for that https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/671

Comment: Interesting approach. As I see, it's meant to provide an authorization point in the zuul server itself. However, where do you tell zuul where the real OAuth Server lies? I mean, you've provided `<zuul hostname>` in the zuul configuration to enable it authorizing over himself, but how does it know the real authorization endpoint?

Comment: I created a poc with extended doc that should answer your previous question  https://github.com/kakawait/uaa-behind-zuul-sample

Comment: I cannot tell you how long it took for me to find this! And you are using JWT! Amazing! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand your question, `spring-cloud-security` (for the `EnableOauth2Sso` part) and `spring-cloud` (for zuul), this is not possible to proxy the calls to the authorization server using zuul.
The main reason being that `spring-cloud-security` secures the Gateway independently (and before accounting for) Zuul routing's logic.

Which means that the (sample configuration from Dave Syer's [OAuth2](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/tree/master/oauth2/) example) `spring.oauth2.client.*` configuration

```
spring:
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize
      clientId: acme
      clientSecret: acmesecret
```

is considered **before** allowing any access to the Zuul's routes `zuul.routes.*`

Moreover this setup enables the *client agent* to store two Cookies: one for the Gateway and one for the Authorization Server.

I hope this helps.