# How to extend Spring Security authentication to Zuul

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-security, netflix-zuul

I have a Netflix Zuul server receiving all HTTP requests and forwarding them to my microservice.

The underlying microservice authenticates users through Facebook oauth API. I receive the user data from Facebook API and I authenticate the user programmatically:

```
public Authentication login(String username, String password) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
    return result;
}
```

With Zuul in front this doesn't work. I think it sets up the session in the microservice environment, but never extends it to Zuul. It works fine when requests go straight to microservice.

What I've done:

I cleared the sensitiveHeaders property in my application.properties:
`zuul.routes.[SERVICE_NAME].sensitiveHeaders=`, but it's meant to work the other way around I think.

How do I setup a session with Zuul?

Edit:

My Zuul configuration:

```
# Zuul proxy
zuul.add-host-header=true
zuul.routes.httpbin.path=/**
zuul.routes.httpbin.serviceId=httpbin
zuul.routes.httbin.sensitiveHeaders=

httpbin.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:8090

ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
```

Comment: You may have to include more details about how you have Zuul configured. For example, do you have the following in your config.
proxy:
  auth:
    routes:
      my-service: oauth2

Comment: I handle all the oauth2 redirects myself in my custom controller and then setup the session myself, I tried it but nothing, not sure if this out of the box `oauth2` helps?

Comment: See if this answer is what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444279/252344

Comment: Not really, I'm not hosting oauth2 authorization server and I don't have an endpoint for giving out tokens. I simply setup a spring security session. In the end I'd just want to see `JSESSIONID` in my cookies, but currently it doesn't get set.